# Pasar oraciones por voz a texto c#

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy terminando una aplicación de reconocimiento de voz en `c#`, pero me reconoce solo palabras (no oraciones), además que algunas de las palabras que me reconoce el programa no son las que pronuncio verbalmente, quisiera que me ayuden para que el programa pueda reconocer frases y oraciones, y ademas me reconozca las palabras correctamente.

Aqui esta el codigo que llevo.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine _Recognition = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        public MainWindow()
        {
}
}
```

---

```
private void btEscuchar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _Recognition.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _Recognition.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
            _Recognition.SpeechRecognized += _Recognition_SpeechRecognized;
            _Recognition.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
```

Saludos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Man, Añade código que usaste, para que se te pueda ayudar, si no lo haces te cerrarán la pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Esta es una pregunta muy interesante y seguro que hay mucha gente interesada. Pero has de formularla de una forma que favorezca el ayudarte, vista : [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y después edítala.

Comment: ya esta.Saludos.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia, ¿qué problema específico tienes con el código que compartes? Por favor, trata de agregar un [mcve] que ilustre el problema concreto que enfrentas. Divide tu problema en partes más pequeñas y manejables, si lo consideras necesario.

Comment: solo quiero que reconozca frases u oraciones largas. solo reconoce palabras

Comment: tal vez si agregaras que tipo de objeto es _Recognition, alguien que lo reconozca podra ayudarte

Comment: @gbianchi está usando [System.Speech.Recognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition(v=vs.110).aspx).  Cuando usas librerías standard de un lenguaje no hace falta decir qué estás usando. Nadie dice "estoy usando la std:string que se define en el standard de C++", eso faltaría. Respecto a la amplitud, lo dudo mucho, probablemente es otro caso de pensar que es muy amplio aquello que no dominas. +1, mantener abierto.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos mas alla de que fuera conocido, pedi que lo agregara para que quedara bien la pregunta. tal vez estaba utilizando una libreria de un tercero o un wrapper. siempre mejor aclarar en algunos casos. Del resto no me hago cargo, le hablaras a tole??

Comment: algo raro que noto en el codigo.. el apreta escuchar.. y el sistema escucha hasta cuando?? tal vez por eso le reconoce una sola palabra y no frases enteras.. no deberia estar escuchando siempre hasta que le diga que pare?

Comment: @gbianchi, es verdad lo que ud escribe, pero deberia mostrarme la frasecompleta, no por partes.

Comment: yo desconozco como funciona esa libreria.. pero no escucha hasta que escucha silencio? si es asi, la frase completa nunca va a salir toda junta.. que pasa si le dictas el abecedario sin respirar? lo imprime todo o solo la A?

Comment: haré la prueba y lo publico. Gracias @gbianchi

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres pasar voz a texto prueba con los servicios cognitivos de speech to text, hace poco me monté una demo similar y solo reconoce las palabras del diccionario, te tienes que fabricar las frases a mano, sino la otra posibilidad es buscar un diccionario.

**EDITO:**
En la misma página de servicios cognitivos de Microsoft hay una demo, acceso a la documentación y a un repositorio de github con codigo fuente para una aplicación WPF.

[Ir a la demo y a la documentación de reconocimiento de voz por Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/services/cognitive-services/speech/)

> Convierta audio con voz en texto. Se puede requerir a la API que se
>   encienda para reconocer audio emitido por el micrófono en tiempo real,
>   para que reconozca audio emitido desde otro origen de audio en tiempo
>   real o para reconocer audio dentro de un archivo.

[Ir al repositorio de github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows)

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola Sergio, si pones un ejemplo de lo que comentas tu respuesta seria estupenda

Comment: genial, gracias @sergioReguera